# Rational Functional Tester - multiple app instances not working

Tags: java, testing, exception, rft, ibm-rational

I've been exploring Rational Functional Tester from IBM and have come across something which is rather frustrating.

According to the following references, it is possible to have multiple instances of an application in a test script. You differentiate between them by passing the *ProcessTestObject* reference to each action:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc%2Ftopics%2FHandling_Ambiguous_Recognition.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/rfttreasures/entry/how_to_test_multiple_instances_of_application_in_one_testcase8?lang=en

So then, with that in mind, I create two instances and call an action to click on a text area. This WORKS without the reference being passed.

```
ProcessTestObject p1 = startApp("MyApp");
ProcessTestObject p2 = startApp("MyApp");

text(p1, DEFAULT_FLAGS).click(atPoint(10,10)); // text() works
```

This fails and gives me an ObjectNotFoundException ("the process is gone"). Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: what is the code for startApp() look like?  The error looks clear. The process died.

Comment: did you see 2 instances of your applications when you run this test?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be having the problem when you start two instances of MyApp.  If there are any common resources that they share, one might crash.